# qgis: generalisation & covex - how to? what plugin?

Tags: qgis, plugins, simplify, generalization, convex-hull

I'm looking for a way to generalize and simlify polygon to remove "internal spikes" as ilustrated below. The violet in input and green expected poligon.

[image: input polygon example]
[image: expected output]

Answer (score 1):

There's a few tools available for simplifying polygons:

- **Simplify geometries**

  ```
  Processing Toolbox > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector geometry tools
  ```

---

- **v.generalize.simplify**

  ```
  Processing Toolbox > GRASS GIS 7 commands > Vector (v.*)
  ```

---

- **PolygonSimplifier**

  ```
  Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins
  ```